# using queryselector to get textContent from td tags without class names

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to create a datascraper using node.

Here is a sample html code for an item that I am trying to scrape:

```
<tr class="cool">
<td>Todd</td>
<td>Bob eats shoes <br/><a href="/cool/donkey" title="fluffy" class="stack">[Stack]</a>
</tr>
```

Here is some code that I am using to extract:

```
cars.forEach(carCard=> {
      const carCool = {
        number: carCard.querySelector('?').textContent,
        date: carCard.querySelector('?').textContent,
      };
    });
```

I was wondering if there was anyway I could get the text of 'Todd' and [Stack] using this query selector. I do not know what I would need to put in place of the question marks. If not is there a different method I can use to accomplish this?

Please help.

Comment: have you tried `querySelector('td')` and `querySelector('a.stack')` ?

Comment: @HymnZzy in the real code there are multiple tds so it would be difficult. is there anyway i can distinguish between td x and td y

Comment: If you know the sequence of `td`s is going to be same, use `querySelectorAll('td')` which will give you an array of all `td`s and then use `index` to get your required `td`

Comment: ah thats a great idea! @HymnZzy

Comment: `document.querySelector("tr.cool > td")` or `document.querySelector("td:first-child")` if  `<td>Todd</td>` is a first child. (or `:nth-child(n)`) see: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```js
// To get all the td fields
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
// to get the content of the td fields
tds.forEach(td => {
  console.log(td.textContent);
})
```